# Gracefully stopping Quarkus application running as Windows service with JNI

Tags: quarkus

We have a Quarkus application that is deployed as an uber jar which is wrapped by an in-house framework that runs it as a Windows service. The framework mirrors the Windows API closely and expects the application to be able to start, then run and finally stop gracefully when signaled by the OS.

The current solution always returns true for start without doing anything (not ideal, but works); it then calls `Quarkus.run();` from the run method, which blocks. When stop is called, it calls `Quarkus.asyncExit();`. That stops the application.

The problem is that Quarkus seems to stop using `System.exit()`, which makes Windows think the service crashed. Is there a way to avoid that and make it return instead, passing control back to the run method (that called `Quarkus.run()`)?

I realize this is not a typical use case for Quarkus, but graceful controlled start and stop from a calling program should be generally useful. We have not yet tried preventing exit with a security manager, as that seems a bit up in the air with Java 17; see [jdk-8199704](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=jdk-8199704).